# Reportlab: Why is two column output reverting to single column?

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

I want to generate two-column pages in Reportlab.  The attached program (adapted from a variety of examples) generates two pages with two columns, then generates single-column pages.

I've tried creating multiple page templates, for first and subsequent pages.  This doesn't change the output.

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Frame, Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus import Spacer, PageTemplate, NextPageTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

doc = SimpleDocTemplate ("try.pdf")
style = styles["Normal"]

#Two Columns
frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, 
               doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col1')
frame2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin+doc.width/2+6, doc.bottomMargin, 
               doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col2')
doc.addPageTemplates(PageTemplate(id='TwoCol', frames=[frame1,frame2]))

Story = []
Story.append (NextPageTemplate(['TwoCol']))

for rec in range (1, 200):
    line = ("<para><b>Paragraph %s:</b> " % rec)
    line += "This is the text of the paragraph. More text of the paragraph."
    line += " Even more text.</para>\n"
    p = Paragraph(line, style)
    Story.append(p)

doc.build (Story)
```

I added the following after "Story.append(p)" to see if it would be a workaround:

```
    if rec % 40 == 0: 
        Story.append (NextPageTemplate(['TwoCol']))
```

Now, pages 1 & 2 are two column, page 3 is one column, pages 4 & 5 are two column.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at SimpleDocTemplate.build().  It creates a full page frame (id='First') and adds this to the document's list of pageTemplates.

It looks like BaseDocTemplate.build() picks up the next pageTemplate for each page it is about to generate.  I think this will cause the default to be selected at times.

I replaced SimpleDocTemplate with BaseDocTemplate.  Now all pages are generated with two columns.